# Scala 3 macros trait arguments

Tags: scala, scala-macros, scala-3

Here is the basic setup:

```
trait MyProduct[A, B](a: A, b:  B)
class X
class Y

class XxY(x: X, y: Y) extends MyProduct(x,y)
```

I'm trying to examine the arguments to the `MyProduct` trait. More specifically I want to extract some information, such as the strings "x" and "y", that indicates which fields of `XxY` are passed to `MyProduct`.

Importantly, I need to satisfy the case with multiple fields of the same type, eg `class XxYxY(x: X, y1: Y, y2: Y) extends MyProduct3(x, y1, y2)`, so reasoning from the type arguments isn't sufficient.

I think maybe the issue is I haven't found a way to get a symbol to the `extends` clause itself. I can find the `ClassDef` for `XxY`, from which I can extract `parents` and get the already constructed type `MyProduct[X,Y]`. I've also looked at the `symbol.declarations` of the enclosing module and the `XxY.<init>` function to see if there might be data that I can use to find the arguments, but none of these seem to have the information I'm looking for.

Looking at the tree for the enclosing module makes me think that perhaps this information is erased and instead needs to be parsed as text from the source code, but I'm hoping someone has a better solution.

*EDIT from comment:*

As input I have a `Type` instance of the enclosing object/module. For example:

```scala
inline def simpleProductTest[T <: Singleton]: String = ${simpleProductTestImpl[T]}

def simpleProductTestImpl[T](using q: Quotes)(using Type[T]): Expr[String] = ???
```

As output I would like something that allows me to examine the arguments to the trait used in the extends clause.

Comment: What do you have as input and what would you like to have as output? It's not clear to me from your question.

Comment: As input I have a `Type` instance of the enclosing object/module. For example,
```inline def simpleProductTest[T <: Singleton]: String = ${simpleProductTestImpl[T]};
def simpleProductTestImpl[T](using q: Quotes)(using Type[T]): Expr[String]. 
```
As output I would like something that allows me to examine the arguments to the trait used in the `extends` clause.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do

```
import scala.quoted.*

object Macros {
  inline def simpleProductTest[T]: Unit = ${simpleProductTestImpl[T]}

  def simpleProductTestImpl[T](using Quotes)(using Type[T]): Expr[Unit] = {
    import quotes.reflect.*
    println(TypeRepr.of[T].typeSymbol.tree.asInstanceOf[TypeDef].rhs)
    '{()}
  }
}
```

you'll see

```
object App {
  trait MyProduct[A, B](a: A, b:  B)
  class X
  class Y

  class XxY(x: X, y: Y, z: Int) extends MyProduct(x,y)

  Macros.simpleProductTest[XxY]
}
```

that there is no information about `x,y`

```
Template(
  DefDef(
    <init>,
    List(List(
      ValDef(x,TypeTree[TypeRef(ThisType(TypeRef(ThisType(TypeRef(NoPrefix,module class <empty>)),module class App$)),class X)],EmptyTree),
      ValDef(y,TypeTree[TypeRef(ThisType(TypeRef(ThisType(TypeRef(NoPrefix,module class <empty>)),module class App$)),class Y)],EmptyTree),
      ValDef(z,TypeTree[TypeRef(TermRef(ThisType(TypeRef(NoPrefix,module class <root>)),object scala),class Int)],EmptyTree)
    )),
    TypeTree[TypeRef(ThisType(TypeRef(ThisType(TypeRef(NoPrefix,module class <empty>)),module class App$)),class XxY)],
    EmptyTree
  ),
  List(
    TypeTree[TypeRef(ThisType(TypeRef(NoPrefix,module class lang)),class Object)],
    TypeTree[AppliedType(TypeRef(ThisType(TypeRef(ThisType(TypeRef(NoPrefix,module class <empty>)),module class App$)),trait MyProduct),
      List(
        TypeRef(ThisType(TypeRef(ThisType(TypeRef(NoPrefix,module class <empty>)),module class App$)),class X),
        TypeRef(ThisType(TypeRef(ThisType(TypeRef(NoPrefix,module class <empty>)),module class App$)),class Y)
      )
    )]
  ),
  ValDef(_,EmptyTree,EmptyTree),
  List(
    ValDef(x,TypeTree[TypeRef(ThisType(TypeRef(ThisType(TypeRef(NoPrefix,module class <empty>)),module class App$)),class X)],EmptyTree),
    ValDef(y,TypeTree[TypeRef(ThisType(TypeRef(ThisType(TypeRef(NoPrefix,module class <empty>)),module class App$)),class Y)],EmptyTree),
    ValDef(z,TypeTree[TypeRef(TermRef(ThisType(TypeRef(NoPrefix,module class <root>)),object scala),class Int)],EmptyTree)
  )
)
```

And `Template` doesn't exist in `scala.quoted.*`, it's `dotty.tools.dotc.ast.Trees.Template`.

But if you print `.tasty` file with [TASTy inspection](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/metaprogramming/tasty-inspect.html)

`libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" %% "scala3-tasty-inspector" % "3.0.0"`

```
import scala.quoted.*
import scala.tasty.inspector.*

class MyInspector extends Inspector:
  def inspect(using Quotes)(tastys: List[Tasty[quotes.type]]): Unit =
    import quotes.reflect.*
    for tasty <- tastys do
      val tree = tasty.ast
      println(tree)

@main def test: Unit =
  val tastyFiles = List("target/scala-3.0.0/classes/App.tasty")
  TastyInspector.inspectTastyFiles(tastyFiles)(new MyInspector)
```

you'll see

```
Template(
  DefDef(
    <init>,
    List(List(
      ValDef(x,Ident(X),EmptyTree),
      ValDef(y,Ident(Y),EmptyTree),
      ValDef(z,Ident(Int),EmptyTree)
    )),
    TypeTree[TypeRef(TermRef(ThisType(TypeRef(NoPrefix,module class <root>)),object scala),Unit)],
    EmptyTree
  ),
  List(
    Apply(Select(New(TypeTree[TypeRef(TermRef(ThisType(TypeRef(NoPrefix,module class java)),object lang),Object)]),<init>),List()),
    Apply(
      TypeApply(
        Select(New(Ident(MyProduct)),<init>),
        List(
          TypeTree[TypeRef(ThisType(TypeRef(ThisType(TypeRef(ThisType(TypeRef(NoPrefix,module class <root>)),module class <empty>)),module class App$)),class X)],
          TypeTree[TypeRef(ThisType(TypeRef(ThisType(TypeRef(ThisType(TypeRef(NoPrefix,module class <root>)),module class <empty>)),module class App$)),class Y)]
        )
      ),
      List(Ident(x), Ident(y))  <--- HERE!!!
    )
  ),
  ValDef(_,EmptyTree,EmptyTree),
  List(
    ValDef(x,TypeTree[TypeRef(ThisType(TypeRef(ThisType(TypeRef(ThisType(TypeRef(NoPrefix,module class <root>)),module class <empty>)),module class App$)),class X)],EmptyTree),
    ValDef(y,TypeTree[TypeRef(ThisType(TypeRef(ThisType(TypeRef(ThisType(TypeRef(NoPrefix,module class <root>)),module class <empty>)),module class App$)),class Y)],EmptyTree),
    ValDef(z,TypeTree[TypeRef(TermRef(ThisType(TypeRef(NoPrefix,module class <root>)),object scala),Int)],EmptyTree)
  )
)
```

that the tree is slightly different and information about `x,y` is there.

In Scaladocs for extension method `.tree` of `Symbol` it's written

```
     *  **Warning**: avoid using this method in macros.
     *
     *  **Caveat**: The tree is not guaranteed to exist unless the compiler
     *  option `-Yretain-trees` is enabled.
```

Let's switch on `-Yretain-trees`

`scalacOptions += "-Yretain-trees"`

Then `Macros.simpleProductTest[XxY]` prints

```
Template(
  DefDef(
    <init>,
    List(List(
      ValDef(x,Ident(X),EmptyTree),
      ValDef(y,Ident(Y),EmptyTree),
      ValDef(z,Ident(Int),EmptyTree)
    )),
    TypeTree[TypeRef(ThisType(TypeRef(NoPrefix,module class scala)),class Unit)],
    EmptyTree
  ),
  List(
    Apply(Select(New(TypeTree[TypeRef(ThisType(TypeRef(NoPrefix,module class lang)),class Object)]),<init>),List()),
    Apply(
      TypeApply(
        Select(New(Ident(MyProduct)),<init>),
        List(
          TypeTree[TypeVar(TypeParamRef(A) -> TypeRef(ThisType(TypeRef(ThisType(TypeRef(NoPrefix,module class <empty>)),module class App$)),class X))],
          TypeTree[TypeVar(TypeParamRef(B) -> TypeRef(ThisType(TypeRef(ThisType(TypeRef(NoPrefix,module class <empty>)),module class App$)),class Y))]
        )
      ),
      List(Ident(x), Ident(y))   <----  AGAIN HERE !!!!
    )
  ),
  ValDef(_,EmptyTree,EmptyTree),
  List(
    ValDef(x,TypeTree[TypeRef(ThisType(TypeRef(ThisType(TypeRef(NoPrefix,module class <empty>)),module class App$)),class X)],EmptyTree),
    ValDef(y,TypeTree[TypeRef(ThisType(TypeRef(ThisType(TypeRef(NoPrefix,module class <empty>)),module class App$)),class Y)],EmptyTree),
    ValDef(z,TypeTree[TypeRef(TermRef(ThisType(TypeRef(NoPrefix,module class <root>)),object scala),class Int)],EmptyTree)
  )
)
```

i.e. tree is again slightly different but information about `x,y` appeared. So the question is now only how to extract this information since it's `dotty.tools.dotc.ast.*`

```
case class Template[-T >: Untyped] private[ast](
  constr: DefDef[T], 
  parentsOrDerived: List[Tree[T]], 
  self: ValDef[T], 
  private var preBody: LazyTreeList[T @uncheckedVariance]
)(implicit @constructorOnly src: SourceFile)
```

So finally

`libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" %% "scala3-compiler" % "3.0.0"`

```
import scala.quoted.*

inline def simpleProductTest[T]: List[String] = ${simpleProductTestImpl[T]}

def simpleProductTestImpl[T](using Quotes)(using Type[T]): Expr[List[String]] = {
  import quotes.reflect.*
  Expr(
    TypeRepr.of[T].typeSymbol.tree.asInstanceOf[TypeDef].rhs
      .asInstanceOf[dotty.tools.dotc.ast.Trees.Template[?]]
      .parentsOrDerived
      .asInstanceOf[List[Apply]]
      .tail.head.args.map(_.symbol.name)
  )
}

Macros.simpleProductTest[XxY] // List(x, y)
```

Comment: @user3747260 See new version.

Comment: It worked! Thanks for also showing the process you used to find it. I have a good idea of how to go about finding this kind of data in the future now.